# $article->title . print_r($article) . var_dump($article);

Tags: php, joomla2.5

Using Joomla 2.5 (but I think this is a php question) in my plugin code for the function onContentAfterSave the following code returns the title but nether the print_r or var_dump return all the values I want to see so I know what is there to pick from

```
$article->title . print_r($article) .  var_dump($article);
```

The value of 1 gets returned by print_r and var_dump. What function should I be using to look inside the $article variable?

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: `var_dump(get_object_vars($article));`

Comment: I encountered similar problem and it looks like `$article->title` needs to be replaced with `$item->title` in J!2.5